# Jquery menu syntax not working to old

Tags: jquery, syntax, menu, slidedown

Hi i always use this code of jquery for menus, the problem is now im using a newer version (i think) of jquery because a dock menu Mac style my client ask,.. actually the menu is working , just the slideDown function dont remain open, so the menu is not working..

I used to use this jquery..

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

whit this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("ul.submenu").parent().append("<span></span>"); 

    $("ul.menu li span").hover(function() { //Al hacer click se ejecuta...

        //Con este codigo aplicamos el movimiento de arriva y abajo para el submenu
        $(this).parent().find("ul.submenu").slideDown('fast').show(); //Menu desplegable al hacer click

        $(this).parent().hover(function() {
        }, function(){
            $(this).parent().find("ul.submenu").slideUp('slow'); //Ocultamos el submenu cuando el raton sale fuera del submenu
        });

        }).hover(function() {
            $(this).addClass("subhover"); //Agregamos la clase subhover
        }, function(){  //Cunado sale el cursor, sacamos la clase
            $(this).removeClass("subhover");
    });

});
</script>
```

This code remains the same, im just using this on my header now..

```
<script src="js/jquery.tools.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/interface.js"></script>
```

The question after all is How can i rewrite those lines to actually make that menu works...

Here is working http://www.dreaminmedia.com/imdr/quienessomos.php

Here is the HTML

```
<div id="menuwrap">
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Inicio</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Tutoriales</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">CSS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Javascript</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">jQuery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">HTML</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHP</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Códigos</a>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li><a href="#">Reloj en Flash</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Fecha con JS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">XML y AS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">RSS y PHP</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">ASP a Excel</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">PHP a Excel</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Sobre Nosotros</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Politica</a></li>

    <li><a href="#">Contactanos</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is event delegation if you are using latest jquery:

change this line:

```
$("ul.menu li span").hover(function() { //Al hacer click se ejecuta...
```

to this:

```
$("#menuwrap").on('hover', 'ul.menu li span', function() { //Al hacer click se ejecuta...
```

@ Your latest comment:

```
$("#menuwrap").on('hover', 'ul.menu li span', function () {
   $(this).addClass("subhover");
}, function () {
   $(this).removeClass("subhover");
});

$("#menuwrap ul.menu li").hover(function () {
     $("> ul.submenu", this).stop().slideDown('fast').show();
}, function () {
     $("> ul.submenu", this).stop().slideUp('slow');
});
```

Comment: I fully replace the code with yours you can see it here http://www.dreaminmedia.com/imdr/quienessomos.php , now is not working at all.

Comment: I just add the HTML to the question may be usefull

Comment: Man you are awesome for the help, but =( working weird (bought open at the same time), you can see  it yourself in the URL mentioned. =(

Edited: I think its almost done!!, just all submenus open at the same time, dont matter wich one i choose.. =)

You rule!!

Comment: @Monclee Thanks and sorry man i was in a hurry try this one now.

Comment: Have you put the latest one with `.stop()`